# iOS - Confirm dialog when leaving controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uialertview, uipageviewcontroller

I have 4 pages in UIPageViewController and there are some inputs in each page. I would like to show alert when user change something on page and tries to swipe to other page. Alert should have two options: stay or continue to next page. I was searching for this and I just found solutions which add alert when user tap (or do something else) and if should continue then segue is performed. But in UIPageViewController (UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll) I don't have much options how to work with slide gesture. I am looking for some way that I could add code to viewWillDisappear and eventually stop disappearing (if user taps stop). But in method viewWillDisappear its too late. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` delegate method in [UIPageViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDelegate/pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:)

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers 
{
     //Do stuff here before the user ends gesture
}
```

Comment: Looks good but one more thing. How can I stop or continue with transition in this delegate method?

Comment: Well, if you show an alert, it will probably stop the transition so you can do it programmatically with this method  `- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion` in [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:)

Comment: You've right. When alert is shown transition is stopped and just need to make "manually" transition if needed. Thanks